# Remove vertices based on some values of an vertices' attribute

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I have a graph with the attribute color (numbers) that represents communities obtained with `fastgreedy.community`. Some of those communities are just compound by few vertices (5 or less).

**1** I would like to remove them, ideally with a function that allow me count the number of vertices per community and remove those vertices associated with small communities. For example, remove vertices of communities smaller than an arbitrary number of vertices. I really have no idea how do this. I will be appreciate any help.

**2** I tried to solve this problem in a very simple way, but without success.

I manually identified those small communities and I tried to remove their vertices  as I show below:

`g2 <-remove.vertex.attribute(g, V(g)[ V(g)[color >13]%--% V(g)[color >13] ])`

I just copied this code from other question and it seems that I didn't understand it very well.

**Update**

Following the advice below, the correct way to do **2** is:

`g3 <-delete.vertices(g, V(g)[ V(g)[color >13] ])`

However, I would still appreciate if someone help me with the part **1** of my question, as I have to repeat it many time and manually doing it will take me for ever.

Again, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name says, `remove.vertex.attribute` removes a vertex attribute. It does not remove vertices. Read this: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.structure.html and use `delete.vertices`.

Comment: This does not actually answer the title question so is not very useful to people landing on this page.

Comment: The answer is in the update of the question itself. But If you think it is not a good answer, just provide another one. I'll be happy to remove this one.